# linq AncestorsAndSelf with null argument

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml

How can I rewrite these two linq queries to one? .AncestorsAndSelf doesn't support null as an element name.

```
        if (ancestorElementName == null)
        {
            ancestorElements =
                currentElement
                .AncestorsAndSelf()
                .Select(
                    .
                    .
                    .
                    );
        }
        else
        {
            ancestorElements =
                currentElement
                .AncestorsAndSelf(ancestorElementName)
                .Select(
                    .
                    .
                    .
                    );
        }
```

Comment: To clarify you want to use linq to select the specified element when it is not null?

Answer (score 0):

How about adding an extension method that takes care of this method selection. That would allow you to keep the rest of the query identical.

As in:

```
public static class MyLinqToXmlExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<XElement> ForAncestorsAndSelf(this XElement e, XName name)
    {
        return name == null ? e.AncestorsAndSelf() : e.AncestorsAndSelf(name);
    }
};
```

Which you could then use as

```
ancestorElements = currentElement
    .ForAncestorsAndSelf(ancestorElementName)
    .Select(
            .
            .
            .
            );
```

Answer (score 0):

Write your own extension, like this:

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
     public static IEnumerable<XElement> MyAncestorsAndSelf(this IEnumerable<XElement> source, XName name)
     {
         if(name == null)
         {
             return source.AncestorsAndSelf();
         }

         return source.AncestorsAndSelf(name);
     }
}
```